# PF rule that can match INPUT and OUTPUT interfaces

Tags: iptables, freebsd, firewall, pfsense

Is there a way with PfSense (or with a FreeBSD PF cmd line) to make a rule that can match INPUT and OUTPUT interfaces like this one in IPTABLES ?

`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.1 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT`